# Using a NSArray to display an image using UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to use an ImageView to be able to display any number between 1 and 6 and be able to display this on a iPhone storyboard but I am having a little difficulty with this. I have using the arc4random() % 6 method to be able to randomize the numbers between 1 and 6, the main problem is being able to display the images that I have uploaded and be able to display this on the simulator. Here is the code I have so far.

This is in the ViewConroller.m

```
- (IBAction)Button:(UIButton *)sender {



// In the viewDidLoad method:
[_Dice1 sizeToFit];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice-1-md.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice-2-md.png"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice-3-hi.png"];
UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice-4.png"];
UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice-5-md.png"];
UIImage *image6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice-6-hi.png"];

NSArray*_imageView = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6], nil];

int dice1 = arc4random() % 6;

if(dice1 == 0){
    [_imageView objectAtIndex:0];
        }
if(dice1 == 1){
    [_imageView objectAtIndex:1];
}
if(dice1 == 2){
    [_imageView objectAtIndex:2];
}
if(dice1 == 3){
    [_imageView objectAtIndex:3];
}
if(dice1 == 4){
    [_imageView objectAtIndex:4];
}
if(dice1 == 5){
    [_imageView objectAtIndex:5];
   }        
}
@end
```

This is in the ViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)Button:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Dice1;
```

Do you guys have any suggestions? Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try actually assigning one of those images to your UIImageView.  Your calls to objectAtIndex: return an image, but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: actully self.Dice1.image = [_imageView objectAtIndex:dice1]; is enough after getting a random index. no need to make too long if condition.

Comment: Yep, really no need in ifs.

Answer (score 0):

So whats problem? Assign your images to your `UIImageView` (`self.Dice1`).

```
    self.Dice1.image=[_imageView objectAtIndex:dice1];
```